# Executing Stored Procedure via sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am attempting to execute a Stored Procedure within another stored procedure. The catch is that the stored procedure name is dynamically built within the first procedure. Here is an example of what I am trying to do ...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPINSVALUE_12345
    @guid uniqueidentifier
AS
    DECLARE @returnValue bit
    DECLARE @spToExec NVARCHAR(255)
    SET @returnValue = 0
    WHILE (@returnValue=0)
    BEGIN
         SET @spToExec = 'SPINSVALUE_' + REPLACE(@guid, '-', '_')
         ... DO OTHER STUFF ...
         EXEC sp_executeSQL @spToExec, N'@returnValue BIT OUTPUT', @returnValue OUTPUT
    END
END
```

I can't seem to get the sp_executeSQL to work. Is it possible to execute a stored procedure this way and get a value from the OUTPUT parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does the proc have a return value or an output value?
here is an example

```
create proc prBlatest
as
return 5
go


DECLARE @chvTableName VARCHAR(100),
@intTableCount INT,
@chvSQL NVARCHAR(100)

SELECT @chvTableName = 'prBlatest'
SELECT @chvSQL = N'exec @intTableCount = ' + @chvTableName

EXEC sp_executesql @chvSQL, N'@intTableCount INT OUTPUT', @intTableCount OUTPUT

SELECT @intTableCount
GO
```

BTW I think that this is a bad idea to have many procs that do similar thing, maybe you need to refactor

Comment: Unfortunately the stored procedure requires 2 parameters ... one input and one output ... when I add that in the statement no longer works

Comment: I realize this is ancient but I ran into this same issue and I wasn't able to find much help via Google.  In case anyone else stumbles upon this post, here is what did the trick for me...  Be sure to add the parameter list to the SQL string as well as the sp_executesql call.  So above you would want to append `+ ' @intTableCount = @intTableCount'` right after `' + @chvTableName'`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SET @spToExec = 'EXEC SPINSVALUE' + REPLACE(@guid, '-', '_') + ' @returnValue OUT'        
EXEC sp_executeSQL @spToExec, N'@returnValue int OUTPUT', @returnValue OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay :D, the following code works perfectly (For N.. output and input parameters) please try this ([source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499)):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Myproc
@parm varchar(10),

@parm1OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT,
@parm2OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT
AS
SELECT @parm1OUT='parm 1' + @parm
SELECT @parm2OUT='parm 2' + @parm
GO
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @parmIN VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @parmRET1 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @parmRET2 VARCHAR(30)
SET @parmIN=' returned'
SET @SQLString=N'EXEC Myproc @parm,
@parm1OUT OUTPUT, @parm2OUT OUTPUT'
SET @ParmDefinition=N'@parm varchar(10),
@parm1OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT,
@parm2OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql
@SQLString,
@ParmDefinition,
@parm=@parmIN,
@parm1OUT=@parmRET1 OUTPUT,@parm2OUT=@parmRET2 OUTPUT

SELECT @parmRET1 AS "parameter 1", @parmRET2 AS "parameter 2"
go
drop procedure Myproc
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to SQLMenace's answer. His answer helped me move in the right direction. In the case where parameters are required for the procedure, they HAVE to be declared in the statement parameter.

```
create proc prBlatest @in int
as
return 5 + @in
go

DECLARE @chvTableName VARCHAR(100),
    @intTableCount INT,
    @chvSQL NVARCHAR(100)

SELECT @chvTableName = 'prBlatest'
SELECT @chvSQL = N'exec @intTableCount = ' + @chvTableName + ' @inputParam' 
        --NOTICE the @in parameter is declared in the statement parameter

EXEC sp_executesql @chvSQL, N'@inputParam int, @intTableCount INT OUTPUT'
    , @inputParam = 5
    , @intTableCount = @intTableCount OUTPUT

SELECT @intTableCount
GO
```

The value of 10 is returned in this case.

Parameters can be set using their names (uses the names from the @params list ) to avoid confusion when there are many.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @return_value int 
SET @SQL = '[dbo].[SpData] @id = 1' 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL ,N'@return_value INT OUTPUT', @return_value OUTPUT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Handy, I used this part to rebuild some parts. Hopefully it will be helpfull for some people;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Myproc
AS
GO
    DECLARE @ProcName  VARCHAR(255) = 'Procedure-Name'
    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @parmIN VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @parmRET1 INT
    DECLARE @v_file_prefix varchar(255) = @ProcName
    DECLARE @v_file_identifier varchar(255) = '004faae0-5927-43f0-a3fb-aa24fcdbbef3'
    DECLARE @v_path varchar(255) = 'C:\INPUT\DataTransfer\Customers\Upload'

    BEGIN 
        --SET @parmIN=' returned'
        SET @SQLString=N'EXEC [src].[Load' + @ProcName + '] @p_file_prefix, @p_file_identifier, @p_path, @RowCount OUTPUT'
        SET @ParmDefinition=N'@p_file_prefix varchar(255), @p_file_identifier varchar(255),@p_path varchar(255),@RowCount INT OUTPUT'
        
        EXECUTE sp_executesql
        @SQLString,
        @ParmDefinition,
        @p_file_prefix=@v_file_prefix,
        @p_file_identifier=@v_file_identifier,
        @p_path=@v_path,
        @RowCount=@parmRET1 OUTPUT
    END;

SELECT @parmRET1 AS "parameter 1"
go
```